# Ember get JSON from non REST url

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have to fetch data from a URL that has query params rather than a RESTful like structure and then return the results in a model to use in a template.

An example of the request URL is

`http://test.net/client/query?owner_uid=OWNER&format=json&per_page=400&r=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,28,29,30,31,32&m5=1&m6=0&user_token=TOKEN`

What the best way to do this with Ember. Should I be using ember-data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just request that JSON via a jQuery AJAX call in the route like this:

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend
   model: ->
      $.getJSON(URL)
```